# Uninstall Redis after manual Installation

Tags: 16.04, redis

I followed this guide to install Redis ["How To Install and Configure Redis on Ubuntu 16.04"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04).
However, now I want to remove the `Redis` from my server (`Ubuntu 16.04`).

The command `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove redis-server` doesn't work as I installed the `Redis` manually..

How can I uninstall it now?

Comment: You did a manual install so `apt-get purge` won't work

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go into the folder where you ran `sudo make install` and run `sudo make uninstall` and that would get rid of it but first you have to stop it see steps below.

Steps:

1. Stop redis with:

   ```
    sudo systemctl stop redis
    sudo systemctl disable redis
   ```
2. Change into install location as per the tutorial link:

   ```
    cd redis-stable
    sudo make uninstall
   ```
3. Get rid of the folders created:

   ```
    sudo rm /etc/redis/redis.conf
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/redis
   ```
4. Remove `redis user`:

   ```
    sudo deluser --group redis # OR
   ```
5. Remove `redis group`:

   ```
    sudo delgroup redis
   ```

Comment: redis group still remains, maybe update your answer to include that last piece of information for completeness, otherwise great answer.